# Appending div after every 4 sections and at the end if there are any sections remaining

Tags: jquery, html, count, append

I'm trying to append a div after every 4 sections and at the end if there are any remaining. So it looks something like this:

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<div></div>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<div></div>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<div></div>
```

I know this code does it after every 4th one:

```html
$("section:nth-child(4n)").after("<div></div>");
```

But I'm not sure how to add it for the remaining. I thought about adding a count system with an if... I'm not very good at coding so I'd appreciate any explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also extend the selector to include the last element with `$("section:nth-child(4n), section:last").after("<div></div>");`.

Comment: Nice. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/koqy4gf7/16/ I'm not sure why this doesn't duplicate divs, though. It must treat doubly-selected elements just once.

Comment: In jquery, the comma is like an `OR` op (https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Once one condition is met, the test is successful.

Comment: Thank you! This was very easy to use and a very neat code I will continue to use in the future :) I gave you the 'right' answer among many good choices because it was the most succinct code.

Answer (score 1):

Using a container element for selection context, check whether the type of the last child element is `section`:

```
$("#box section:nth-child(4n)").after("<div></div>");

if ($('#box').children().last().is('section')) {
    $('#box').append("<div></div>");
}
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/koqy4gf7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Count the total number of sections, mod 4 and if there's a remainder, add the div after the last section

```
var div = $('<div>');
var sectionsLen = $('section').length;
if(sectionsLen % 4 !== 0) {
   $('#box').children().last().append(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is a div after last section. If not add a new one. Here is the code

```
$("section:nth-child(4n)").after("<div></div>");
if (!$("section:last").next().is('div')) {
    $("section:last").after("<div></div>");
}
```

$("section:last") selects the last section and then next() method selects the next element and then checks if it is a div. If it is not then adds a div after last section. Hope this helps.